# How to change text and back arrow color of PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder Android

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am trying to change textColor and arrow color of actionbar of PlaceAutoComplete Intent to white instead of black.

style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

and The intent call is with FullScreen and the code is:

```
     try {
    Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)                                                                    .build(BaseActivity.this);
  startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
  dialog.dismiss();
} catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
 // TODO: Handle the error.
} catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
 // TODO: Handle the error.
}catch (Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

[image]

Comment: have you done it?

Comment: @Rohit no, if you able to find solution please share here will give you upvote :)

Comment: @Rohit its something related with theme

Comment: @Rohit can i have your email id?

Comment: I have also not done

Comment: Did u find out how? Please share it with me

Comment: @MRu no not yet...

Comment: I have been looking for a similar solution as well.